# THREE.js Car movement on the Road

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I am making a car game in THREE.js. The problem that I am facing is that I made a Plane Road and put the car on it. Now I made a terrain but I don't know how can I build the relationship between the car and the road so that car should move on the road not in the road, like in the real life.

I try to figure out this issue by calculating the vertices's height of the plane and set the car position above that height but that is not working for me below is the code.

```
for(var k = 0; k < ground.geometry.vertices.length; k++){

    localObject.position.y = ground.geometry.vertices[k].y + 1;
}
```

Help me in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

You need to compute the bounding box of the car like so

```
car.geometry.computeBoundingBox ();
var bBox = car.geometry.boundingBox;
```

and place your plane at bBox.min.y;

```
ground.position.y = bBox.min.y;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it not working, can you help me a little bit more.

Comment: Can you provide an image to see the problem? Or a jsfiddle?

Comment: This is the link of Image **http://i.imgur.com/QDwMgAA.jpg**. It can be seen that car is going over the surface rather it goes on same straight path and inside the terrain.

Comment: Before you said the car is moving on a road so I naturally assumed the road is flat (the code above was for that case). But you are moving on a terrain which has a slope. It would be close to impossible to match the slope of the terrain and the slope of the plane that the wheels of the car create. If you don't require something perfect at each animation step, you need to send a ray from the center of the bounding box of the car towards the terrain. Read the intersected triangle, find its slope and match the slope of the car wheels to the slope of the triangle.